# invalid find handle when iterating directory on Windows

Tags: c, windows, file, loops

I'm being presented with an invalid file error when iterating over a local directory (as per the error checking in place) however I cannot pinpoint what is causing this exactly. Is there anything strikingly obvious that could be causing this?

```
#define MAX_PATHNAME_LEN 260

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError;
    char DirSpec[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];

    argv[0] = "\N:\\Joe\\My Documents\\";
    snprintf(DirSpec, "%s\\*", argv[0]);

    // Find the first file in the directory.
    hFind = FindFirstFile(DirSpec, &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Invalid file handle. Error is %u.\n", GetLastError());
        return (-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("First file name is %s.\n", FindFileData.cFileName);  
            // List all the other files in the directory.
            while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
            {
                printf("Next file name is %s.\n", FindFileData.cFileName); 
            }

        dwError = GetLastError();
        FindClose(hFind);
        if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
        {
            printf("FindNextFile error. Error is %u.\n", dwError);
            return (-1);
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

The directory is correct, however it does not appear to scan within the folder correctly. I am using Visual Studio 2019 to write/compile this.

Comment: `argv[1] =...` ? Are you sure `argv` has 2 elements at all?

Comment: You have at least two issues. `argv[]` does not belong to you to modify. It's for command line parameters passed in to `main()`. You shouldn't be assigning to `argv[0]` anyway; it's the entire path and filename of your own executable.  And what is `\N:` supposed to represent? It's an invalid drive specifier, so your *The directory is correct* is incorrect.  (Oh, and a third issue for later: `MAX_PATHNAME_LEN=200` is wrong. There can be more than 200 characters in a pathname under modern Windows versions.)

Comment: Apart from the foregoing, the line `snprintf(DirSpec, ...` is placing 4 consecutive backslashes in `DirSpec`, so 2 after being escaped.

Comment: @WeatherVane, consecutive slashes are collapsed to a single slash, except obviously not at the beginning of a path.

Comment: @WeatherVane, you're talking about escaping backslash in a string literal. I'm talking about collapsing forward slash and backslash in Windows path normalization. It's fine to repeat slashes in a path, except at the beginning since it's special cased for UNC paths.

Comment: @eryksun yes I've just verified that. It's still muddled style though.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to define

`#define MAX_PATHNAME_LEN 260`

Windows already defines

`#define MAX_PATH 260`

Second, if you are prepending the `N:` drive because it's a network share, it needs to be `\\\\N:\\`, so that the escaped string is `\\N:\`.

Third, you really should *not* be writing to `argv[]`. The C standard makes absolutely no provision for it being writable, and you have no way of knowing if you are writing off the end of the buffer. Use this instead:

```
char basePath[] = "\\\\N:\\Joe\\My Documents\\";
```

Your call to `snprintf(DirSpec, "%s\\*", argv[0]);` doesn't include the length of the destination buffer, so it's a toss-up how that's going to work out. Try

```
snprintf(DirSpec, MAX_PATH, "%s*", basePath);
```

Note that the backslashes have been removed from the format string, because the wildcard for directory contents for the `FindFirstFile()` function is `DirPath\*`, and your base path already ends in a backslash.